# memory issue regarding reading frames of a video in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory, frame

i am trying to read numbers of frames using mmreader function in a given video but matlab gives an error by saying

> ??? Not enough memory available for 1515 frames.
>
> i have tried using the command **clear all** and **clear** but this problem is consistent   could someone please help me out ??

Comment: Try restarting MATLAB or your computer? How big is the file you're trying to create? It might be bigger than the amount of memory available to MATLAB

Comment: use VideoReader. mmreader can read videos of only limited size.

Comment: Thanks for the help , but the problem is VideoReader also reads video of limited size that is approx. 990 frame..

Answer (score 0):

Matlab 32 bits is limited in the maximal size of its matrix. 
With Videos you frequentely touches it.

Are you using 32 or 64 bits?